# Identify a terminal-services user by a simple http request? (not authentification)

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, http-headers, terminal-services

it's a little bit weird, but a 3rd party application has an embedded IE with a configureable static URL. This IE calls my webserver (nodeJS). The application  has no parameter for the url, so I have a simple nodeJS app which starts with the login of the user and connect to the webserver (websocket). This app is able to see the dynamic parameter of the 3rd party app by looking in the user registry. Both together I would the information to bring the right data to the embedded IE. But how can the webserver relate the IE request to the websocket connection of the "registry app". The websocket app knows the NT username and many more, but the IE only sends a simple http request.

If it wasn't a terminal-services, I would the IE run over the a local webserver, which would forwarding the request plus the registry data to the real webserver (like a proxy). But it's a terminal-services, so there is the port blocking problem. Or is there a way to bind a server to a kind of "virtual per user ip" on the same port?

//Jonny